# How does sorting work with limit in kotlin exposed model?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I have following snippet of code:

```
UserDataModel
                .find {
                    UserDataTable.type eq type and (
                            UserDataTable.userId eq userId
                            )
                }
                .limit(count)
                .sortedByDescending { it.timestamp }
```

`sortedByDescending` is a part of kotlin collections API. The my main concern is: how does exposed lib return ***top*** (according to timestamp) `count` rows from table if select query looks like this and does not contain ORDER BY clause?

```
SELECT USERDATA.ID, USERDATA.USER_ID, USERDATA.TYPE,
USERDATA.PAYLOAD, USERDATA."TIMESTAMP"
FROM USERDATA 
WHERE USERDATA.TYPE = 'testType'
and USERDATA.USER_ID = 'mockUser'
LIMIT 4
```

And is it possible that sometimes or somehow returned result would be different for the same data?

Really struggled here. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're sorting the results **after** query has been executed.

You need to use `orderBy` method as described in [docs](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/DSL#order-by)

```
UserDataModel
  .find {
    UserDataTable.type eq type and (UserDataTable.userId eq userId)
  }
  .limit(count)
  .orderBy(UserDataTable.timestamp to SortOrder.DESC)
```

Comment: `.orderBy(UserDataTable.timestamp to false)` is deprecated in favor to `.orderBy(UserDataTable.timestamp to SortOrder.DESC)`. I will update the wiki page.

Comment: My problem was in outdated version of exposed (0.11). It does not contain  orderBy method. May be this info will help someone